# Not able to customize the theme using Nuxt and iView

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, iview

I'm trying to configurate my custom theme on iview, however i'm getting the following error:

`` Error evaluating function `unit`: the first argument to unit must be a number. Have you forgotten parenthesis? ``

The error is related with the less an less-loader. when i remove the line that triggers the error the code works fine. However this files is located in node_modules. So there's not much that i can do about it.

Here is a link to reproduce the error:
https://github.com/Jeanpdt/iviewnuxtapp